# Custom keyword colors in JetBrains WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, color-scheme, jetbrains-ide

Is there an easy way to differentiate keyword colors in WebStorm (or any JetBrains IDE)? Like Sublime Text or Atom, I'd like `function` to be a different color from `var`, `this`, `if`, etc.

I've found good answers on how to import TextMate bundles, but given how much flexibility and customization is baked into the IDE, I have to hope there's a simpler way.

(Relatedly, there is a Custom keywords section under settings > editor > colors & fonts, but I can't define or change the preset keywords. Can anything be done with this?)

Comment: Nope. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7247 , https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473

Comment: *"Relatedly, there is a Custom keywords section under settings > editor > colors & fonts, but I can't define or change the preset keywords"* -- `Colors & Fonts | Custom`? That's a different thing -- those are styles that will be used by user created file types / TextMate bundles.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for the response -- been curious about those custom keywords forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the text color in setting. Go to `File->Settings->JavaScript`  then click on Save Color scheme as...You will be able to modify the color scheme as you want. Or you can [download](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) theme and import it in your preferences